# How to combine project Unwind and group in moongoose

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have complicated documents in collection hotels, i want to project only the hotel name , _id , city and coun of standard , deluxe and suite rooms in that particular hotel , how do i do it.

Here's My documents

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("59f9b27970bc1d12048e323f"),
"type" : "variable",
"country" : "Uae",
"city" : "Dubai",
"rating" : "3 star",
"name" : "taj",
"rooms" : [ 
    {
        "roomNo" : "12",
        "type" : "Standard",
        "maxOccupancy" : "3",
        "reserved" : [ 
            {
                "from" : "2017-12-06",
                "to" : "2017-12-08"
            }
        ],
        "mealPlan" : [ 
            {
                "type" : "AP",
                "perDblRoom" : "10,334",
                "extraPaxWithBed" : "3,953",
                "extraPaxChildWithBed" : "3,953",
                "extraPaxChildNoBed" : "2,682",
                "perSglRoom" : "17,355",
                "season" : "high"
            }, 
            {
                "type" : "AP",
                "perDblRoom" : "9,334",
                "extraPaxWithBed" : "3,953",
                "extraPaxChildWithBed" : "3,953",
                "extraPaxChildNoBed" : "2,682",
                "perSglRoom" : "6,355",
                "season" : "low"
            }, 
            {
                "type" : "CAP",
                "perDblRoom" : "10,334",
                "extraPaxWithBed" : "3,953",
                "extraPaxChildWithBed" : "3,953",
                "extraPaxChildNoBed" : "2,682",
                "perSglRoom" : "17,355",
                "season" : "high"
            }, 
            {
                "type" : "CAP",
                "perDblRoom" : "9,334",
                "extraPaxWithBed" : "3,953",
                "extraPaxChildWithBed" : "3,953",
                "extraPaxChildNoBed" : "2,682",
                "perSglRoom" : "6,355",
                "season" : "low"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "roomNo" : "10",
        "type" : "Deluxe",
        "maxOccupancy" : "6",
        "reserved" : [ 
            {
                "from" : "2017-12-09",
                "to" : "2017-12-12"
            }, 
            {
                "from" : "2017-12-13",
                "to" : "2017-12-16"
            }, 
            {
                "from" : "2017-12-18",
                "to" : "2017-12-20"
            }
        ],
        "mealPlan" : [ 
            {
                "type" : "AP",
                "perDblRoom" : "10,334",
                "extraPaxWithBed" : "3,953",
                "extraPaxChildWithBed" : "3,953",
                "extraPaxChildNoBed" : "2,682",
                "perSglRoom" : "17,355",
                "season" : "high"
            }, 
            {
                "type" : "AP",
                "perDblRoom" : "9,334",
                "extraPaxWithBed" : "3,953",
                "extraPaxChildWithBed" : "3,953",
                "extraPaxChildNoBed" : "2,682",
                "perSglRoom" : "6,355",
                "season" : "low"
            }, 
            {
                "type" : "CAP",
                "perDblRoom" : "10,334",
                "extraPaxWithBed" : "3,953",
                "extraPaxChildWithBed" : "3,953",
                "extraPaxChildNoBed" : "2,682",
                "perSglRoom" : "17,355",
                "season" : "high"
            }, 
            {
                "type" : "CAP",
                "perDblRoom" : "9,334",
                "extraPaxWithBed" : "3,953",
                "extraPaxChildWithBed" : "3,953",
                "extraPaxChildNoBed" : "2,682",
                "perSglRoom" : "6,355",
                "season" : "low"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "roomNo" : "8",
        "type" : "Suite",
        "maxOccupancy" : "6",
        "reserved" : [ 
            {
                "from" : "2017-12-09",
                "to" : "2017-12-12"
            }, 
            {
                "from" : "2017-12-13",
                "to" : "2017-12-14"
            }, 
            {
                "from" : "2017-12-18",
                "to" : "2017-12-20"
            }
        ],
        "mealPlan" : [ 
            {
                "type" : "AP",
                "perDblRoom" : "10,334",
                "extraPaxWithBed" : "3,953",
                "extraPaxChildWithBed" : "3,953",
                "extraPaxChildNoBed" : "2,682",
                "perSglRoom" : "17,355",
                "season" : "high"
            }, 
            {
                "type" : "AP",
                "perDblRoom" : "9,334",
                "extraPaxWithBed" : "3,953",
                "extraPaxChildWithBed" : "3,953",
                "extraPaxChildNoBed" : "2,682",
                "perSglRoom" : "6,355",
                "season" : "low"
            }, 
            {
                "type" : "CAP",
                "perDblRoom" : "10,334",
                "extraPaxWithBed" : "3,953",
                "extraPaxChildWithBed" : "3,953",
                "extraPaxChildNoBed" : "2,682",
                "perSglRoom" : "17,355",
                "season" : "high"
            }, 
            {
                "type" : "CAP",
                "perDblRoom" : "9,334",
                "extraPaxWithBed" : "3,953",
                "extraPaxChildWithBed" : "3,953",
                "extraPaxChildNoBed" : "2,682",
                "perSglRoom" : "6,355",
                "season" : "low"
            }
        ]
    }
]
 }
```

The output i want should be

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("59f9b27970bc1d12048e323f"),
  "name" : "taj",
  "rating" : "3 star",
  "city" : "Dubai",
  "standard" : 4, // count of standard rooms in the hotel
  "deluxe" : 4,
  "suite" : 4
},{
 "_id" : ObjectId("59f9b27970bc1d12048e3233"),
  "name" : "hyatt",
  "rating" : "3 star",
  "city" : "Dubai",
  "standard" : 4, // count of standard rooms in the hotel
  "deluxe" : 4,
  "suite" : 4
}
```

This is the output i need from the collection of hotels, I read lot in mongodb documentation and came across this methods like unwind project and group , but unable to figure out a way for this output

Query :

```
Hotel.aggregate(
        [{
            "$project": {
              "top": {
                "_id": "$_id",
                "name": "$name",
                "rating": "$rating",
                "city": "$city"
              },
              "rooms": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "$unwind": "$rooms"
          },
          {
            "$group": {
              "_id": {
                "id": "$_id",
                "type": "$rooms.type"
              },
              "count": {
                "$sum": 1
              },
              "top": {
                "$first": "$top"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "$sort": {
              "_id.type": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "$group": {
              "_id": "$_id.id",
              "top": {
                "$first": "$top"
              },
              "typeandcount": {
                "$push": {
                  "k": "$_id.type",
                  "v": "$count"
                }
              },
            }
          },
          {"$replaceRoot":{
            "newRoot":{
              "$arrayToObject":{
                "$concatArrays":[
                  {"$objectToArray":"$top"},
                  "$typeandcount"
                ]
              }
            }
          }}
        ]
      )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below aggregation in 3.6 version.

Add all top fields that you would like to keep in the output response. First `$group` to create the count the type of hotels type and second group to create array of type and count value pairs followed by `$mergeObjects` to merge top key value with `$arrayToObject`, which produces type key and count value pairs, to generate the expected response.

`$replaceRoot` to promote the document to the top level.

```
db.colname.aggregate([
  {"$project":{
    "top":{"_id":"$_id","name":"$name","rating":"$rating","city":"$city"},
    "rooms":1
  }},
  {"$unwind":"$rooms"},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":{"id":"$_id","type":"$rooms.type"},
    "count":{"$sum":1},
    "top":{"$first":"$top"}
  }},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":"$_id.id",
    "top":{"$first":"$top"},
    "typeandcount":{"$push":{"k":"$_id.type","v":"$count"}}
  }},
  {"$replaceRoot":{
    "newRoot":{"$mergeObjects":["$top",{"$arrayToObject":"$typeandcount"}]}
  }}
])
```

For 3.4

Replace final stage with

```
{"$replaceRoot":{
  "newRoot":{
    "$arrayToObject":{
      "$concatArrays":[
        {"$objectToArray":"$top"},
        "$typeandcount"
      ]
    }
  }
}}
```

Comment: thanks for the help it worked , except for the $mergeobject , for that i have to update to 3.6

Comment: sorry i am new to mean, i am using mongoose in my project, and arrayToObject is not supported,

Comment: Use mongoose. Can I see your query ? arrayToObject is in 3.4. Are you sure your version is 3.4 ?

Comment: getting error MongoError: Unrecognized expression '$arrayToObject'

Comment: @mp123 you are not on 3.4. How did you check ? Check server version. Run db.version() on shell

Comment: i opened mongo shell got  version 3.4.1

Comment: yes i checked its version 3.4.1 , i have updated my question please check for the query Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry arrayToObject and objectToArrat are in 3.4.4. Can you update to latest 3.4 version ?